# System.Web returns HttpRequest object that does not return UserHostAddress correctly with IPV6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ipv6

We are writing an MVC 4 application and our servers have been updated to use IPV6.  The System.Web namespace provides an HttpRequest object we are trying to use, namely the HttpRequest.UserHostAddress property.  This property is returning unusable values ("::1") for IP address, and I need to know where else I can look in the client application for the correct IP address.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: `::1` is better known as `localhost`

Comment: So, when running in development, you cannot capture the full ip address of the client? (which is obviously the same machine.)  How can you write software to capture and record, or check for security purposes, the IP address, if it is not returned?  Am I just supposed to "trust" that the correct value will be returned in a production environment?  I'm not terribly comfortable with that...

Comment: Relying on IP for authentication is highly dangerous I would recommend against it as it is easy to spoof IP addresses.

Comment: It's not the sole piece of authentication, just one piece.  I know it can be spoofed, my question remains: Is there another way to get the client IP besides System.Web.Request.UserHostAddress?

Comment: When you are developing and testing on your local host then `::1` *is* the full IP address of the client :)

Comment: That is a perfectly valid IP address.